# Android - how to set text for google+ signin button after authenticated

Tags: android, text, google-plus

I have an android example using `Google+ signin` service. When start app, `Google+ signin` button appear with `Login` string.

How to set text `Logout` for `Google+ signin` button after connected and authenticated.
Help me this issue.

Comment: follow the following link 
http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.com/2013/05/google-plus-integration-in-android.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After successful connection has been established by the GooglePlus client, the **`onConnected()`** callback is invoked.

So, all you need to do is change the text of the Button as soon as the user has been logged in.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected() {
        //called after successful connection
        setGooglePlusButtonText(signInButton, R.string.googleplus_signout);

    }


protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) v;
            mTextView.setText(buttonText);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But: The method setText(String) is undefined for the type SignInButton. SignInButton doesn't include setText() method.

Comment: @user3161772 : Sorry. I assumed that you were using custom Button. Well, if you don't want to customise it, you can check out my updated answer. Works well for the default SignInButton.

Answer (score 1):

Use native Button for sign in/sign out with backgound - `@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_dark`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/gplus_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/connect_with_gplus"
        android:background="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this after connecting:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected() {

        Toast.makeText(this, " connected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        btnSignIn.setText(getString(R.string.btn_signout));

            }
```

Comment: But: The method setText(String) is undefined for the type SignInButton. SignInButton doesn't include setText() method.